# Video.js - Want to create a Youtube like playlist

Tags: jquery, html, video.js

I need to create a youtube like playlist with Video.js :

[image]

And have no idea how, could not find anything helpful on google, will appreciate if you can point me to some tutorials or give me some indicators as to how, that will be great !!

Many thanks !!

Comment: Any books you know about that describes about creating a video play list for your own videos - Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use HTML5 Video Player which comes with playlists both right and bottom , you can see the demo and buy it from :

```
http://www.videoplayerhtml5.com/index_rightsideplaylist_universalwhite.html
```

Here is the pic :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also download playlist plugins from the following site for Video.js

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/wiki/Plugins